# How do i get the answer of an equation in dart? X*A+B=0

Tags: flutter, dart

### Hi every body

How do i get the answer of an equation in dart?   X*A+B=0

thank you ,

=======> update <=====

sorry if I was not clear enough, in fact I want to create a program which allows to solve an equation of 1 degree (with only one unknown)
of which: A, B, X is double
if (A = 0) {
if (B = 0) {print ("the solution is the set of doubles")
else print ("no solution")
endif
otherwise
x = -B / A
end if
i want to make this on DART code
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well question is not clear but.. Lets try

So if you want to make some calc, you can always make simple function like:

```
double getEquation(double X, double A, double B){
  return X*A+B;
```

And then use it like:

```
  double answer = getEquation(2,3,4);
  print(answer);
```

But if you asking about bool operation then:

```
    void main() {
    bool answer = getEquation(2,3,4);
    print(answer);
   }



bool getEquation(double X, double A, double B){
      return X*A+B==0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you read input from `stdin`

You have to impoert `dart:io` for `stdin` and `dart:convert` for utf encoding from input.

```
1
2
```

```
the solution is -2.0
```

```
0
5
```

```
no solution
```

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

double readLineAsNumber() => double.parse(stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8)!);

void main() {
  double A = readLineAsNumber();
  double B = readLineAsNumber();

  if (A == 0) {
    if (B == 0) {
      print('the solution is the set of doubles');
    } else {
      print('no solution');
    }
  } else {
    double X = -B / A;
    print('the solution is $X');
  }
}
```